# Recursion problem T(n)=3T(n/3)+3n

Tags: recursion, discrete-mathematics

I just need help solving this problem. I know I'm supposed to be using the Master's Theorem but I don't know where to start

Comment: The solution is a direct application of the theorem. You just need to read the statement and check which condition applies.

Comment: And if you can't figure it out, calculate T(729) by hand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solving or approximating recurrence relations for sequences of numbers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

$$T(n)=3T\left(\frac n3\right)+3n=9T\left(\frac n9\right)+3\frac n3+3n=27T\left(\frac n{27}\right)+3\frac n{27}+3\frac n3+3n=\cdots$$

So for an exact power of $3$, you get

$$nT(1)+3\frac{3n-3}2.$$

Comment: Please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/594).

Comment: I think you lost a factor 3 at the 3 (n/3) which should be 9 (n/3). And you do that for every recursion level, which means k times if n = 3^k, or a factor of log_3(n)